# Keeping passwords in plain text in "value" attribute. Addons can use this for password leaking

Tags: web-application

Either there is a security hole or I'm missing information about something.

While I was testing how [Surfingkeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/surfingkeys_ff) addon works I've noticed that it has command `yf` to copy form content on current web page. I though about testing it on "Sign In" and "Log In" forms on few websites to see if it would be able to retrieve typed passwords in plain text. It was successful if standardized `<form>` tags were used.

Then I've noticed that in most web applications password is kept in `<input value="">` attribute in plain text which to me seems like by-standard security hole for whole W3 stack (HTML, CSS, JS, etc.). If this addon was able to get password from DOM then any addon can do that. The only piece missing is sending that data to server of a 3rd party who are owners of such malicious addon - such situation already had place with [Stylish](https://robertheaton.com/2018/07/02/stylish-browser-extension-steals-your-internet-history/).

So attack scenario looks like this:

1. Company "mal1c1ous" buys popular web addon.
2. They add to addon generic `<form>` parser script which retrieves data from `<input value="">`.
3. For each known website they make their addon "decorate" submit buttons with script which on click 1st sends request with credentials to their server and then to host of that website. Or they just send requests each time parser script is able to get new data.
4. After some time they perform an attack using gathered credentials.

I find that scenario possible show me that it can't happen. Also my question is: given that is Web security flawed by design? Why `<input type="password" value="">` is both visible to the user and accessible for addons in plain text?

The thing is that no one discourages from using `<input value="">` as a password holder it seems that there is no other option by standard. Web developers can only come up with their own ideas to obfuscate where a password is stored before request is made.

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of [Aren't browser extensions a critical security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193534/arent-browser-extensions-a-critical-security-risk). It is known that extension can do almost anything on a site as can do JavaScript on the site. And even if the password would be kept somewhere else instead of the input field - at the end it has to be submitted to the server and an extension can hijack or manipulate this request too.

Comment: It is definitely a security "issue", but there are even more obvious ones in the same vein. For example, have you every copied your password? Well, any running application on your computer has the ability to read your password. Your password will be in plain text (locally) at many points in time. Be cautious of what software/extensions you install.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich This general question gives an answer to mine. Then why after so many years no one made addons more secure? Permissions for addons won't do.

Comment: @Thomas You mean copied in plain text form? In such case I can see the hole but from that point it's hard to get the context of what particular clipboard content is and where it's used.

Comment: @WloHu: *"Then why after so many years no one made addons more secure? __Permissions for addons won't do__."* - But what would do? It is unfortunately not that simple because on the one side an extension needs enough power to provide something useful and on the other side this power can be abused. Extension are in a way similar to programs you install on your computer - how you can be sure that they (only) do what they claim because they have enough permissions to do lots of harm.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Web browsers may block read and write access to some DOM elements or make them not accessible for addons. That is first thing which came to my mind. There are ways but it seems like no one cares.

Comment: @WloHu: This would for example make it impossible for password managers to fill in the passwords and to store the manuelle filled in passwords for later. And, as long as the addon can inject Javascript into the page it could likely work around these restrictions anyway.